How to mock jwtDecode
Hello I am trying to write a test to decode a token using jwtDecode, and my code is as follows.
it('should test labId with more than 4 chars', inject([OauthService], (oauthService: OauthService) => {

const parsedToken = { principal: '1234lab' };  
spyOn(jwtDecode, 'default').and.returnValue(parsedToken);   
component.setUpOAuth();  oauthService.onLoggedIn.next(); 
expect(LabIdManager.labId).toBe('1234lab');

}));

However I keep getting the following error.
Argument of type '"default"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
Any help would greatly appreciated.
This the code my component class
public setUpOAuth() {  

this.subs.add = this.oauth.onLoggedIn.subscribe((token: AccessToken) => {    
console.log('****Token: ', token.toString());     
TokenManager.token = token.toString();     
console.log('TokenManager: ', TokenManager.token);     
 
const parsedToken = token       
     ? (jwtDecode(token.toString()) as TokenProfile)       
     : ({} as TokenProfile);      
if (parsedToken && parsedToken.principal) {       
    LabIdManager.labId = parsedToken.principal.toString();       
     console.log('****LabId: ', LabIdManager.labId);     
}      
}



is jwtDecode a provider of your component?

Hello, I have added the component code above.   Thanks.
